# Install postgresql. Why is initdb unavailable?

Tags: postgresql, database

I'm following [these instructions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/creating-cluster.html), however I can only get to step 17.2.

Despite installing postgresql successfully via the

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

command, upon running

```
initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Ubuntu tells me that it 'initdb' isn't installed. The instructions tell me this command is installed by

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

so what's going on? I can make initdb available by installing postgres-xc, but I think postgres-xc is just some weird third party rubbish, and it's not detailed in the instructions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`initdb` is intended to be run under the postgres user account that is created during the install. After installing postgresql you can do:

`sudo su - postgres`

Then you should be able to run `initdb`.

Comment: Quoting from /usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz:
`Please note that you can of course also use the upstream tools for
creating clusters, such as initdb(1). However, please note that in
this case you cannot expect *any* of above pg_* tools to work, since they use different configuration settings and file locations. If in doubt, then do *not* use initdb, but only pg_createcluster. Since merely installing postgresql-X.Y will already set up a default cluster which is ready to work, most people do not need to bother about initdb or pg_createcluster at all.`

Comment: Even after switching to the postgres user I still get this error

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Ubuntu Server 14 using Postgres 9.6.

Comment: It does not work, since `initdb` is in `/usr/lib/postgresql/X.X/bin/`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an artificial limitation introduced by the Debian package, and the documentation FUD describes this. Note that `pg_createcluster` is another Debian-ism which seems to be absent in newer versions.

Answer (score 32):

You will find `initdb` under `/usr/lib/postgresql/x.y/bin/`.  See also `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.Debian.gz` for more information on the setup on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer.  `initdb` is the underlying command but Debian and Ubuntu users should be using pg_createcluster and its related suite of commands.  Furthermore you normally do not need to `initdb` OR `pg_createcluster` after `apt-get install postgresql` because the standard install already creates a default cluster, with a server and default/template databases, for you.  The README Peter mentions above is worth your time to read.

Comment: @cdaddr No, you usually don't need it after installing postgres. Still, if you find yourself in need of recreating a cluster quickly and don't want to bother with reinstalling postgres or if you need to initialise a new database in a non-standard location this may come in handy. So yes, this is a great answer.

Comment: Works. And it's the best because this way I can be sure which version I'm using.

Comment: we are searching for initdb because, tutorial says so
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/creating-cluster.html

Comment: ... but: `ls -l /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/` returns:
`
total 36
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34888 Aug 13 23:56 pg_config*`
and running `pg_createcluster ...args` returns:
`
Error: no initdb program for version 11 found
`
So the package appears to be broke.

Answer (score 2):

`initdb` is not installed as user executable. Is only installed in `/usr/lib/postgresql/X.X/bin/`, because it always depends on the version. `initdb` can only be executed from that specific directory.

As mentioned in other answers, installation of postgres creates a default directory that may be in a limited partition. Users may want to change this, but it requires other steps also. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901481/postgresql-change-the-data-directory).

Answer (score 0):

if you install postgresql and got `initdb: command not found`

you should add below line in ~/.bashrc (OR .zshrc) file:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/x.y/bin/`

and then

`source ~/.bashrc`

Actually the initdb is exist in that path.
after that you can use initdb command.

Answer (score -2):

Follow the following steps with user root

1. `passwd postgres` - your password
2. `su postgres`
3. `psql`
4. Create a user with your user name like `CREATE USER SAM ;`
5. `create database sam;`
6. Log out and type `psql <your_user>`

Comment: This answer does not address the question directly at all.